# Two tasks using the same Serial Port in Windows IOT

Tags: c#, windows, serialization, task

so far, I have created a background app which main task is to read/write to the serial port. To do this I created a helper class which takes care of the serial communication. This helper class is based on this example (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart), and the first thing it does is to connect to the serial device. This works great.

Now I want to add an App Service to the background app so that I can send messages through the serial from a second foreground app.

My problem is that using the same helper class doesn't work, as I cannot open the connection two times. Is there any way to share the serial connection betwwen two tasks? I thought about using a semaphore, so that both tasks don't send messages at the same time, but still I have the problem of needing to open the connection two times.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The serial port does not allow multiple connection because it has no sense having more than once a time. If it were possible, how could you deal a send/receive in a concurrency context? You'd need a physical protocol to deal with it, but the serial one is basically a shift-register.

You have two options: exclusive access to multiple tasks, or exclusive access to a single proxy, which manages the concurrency of the tasks.

The first option seems to me the simpler: define a subject which will open the serial port. Then, various threads (not just tasks) should access the opened port mutexed by a lock: let's say that a thread should send something to the serial and wait for the answer (or timeout). After that must release the lock for another thread pending.

I implemented something similar years ago. The libraries aren't targeting Windows IoT, but the code would be not so different.

http://cetdevelop.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your answer. This example does what you suggest, I think. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx I understand how it works, but this is done within the same class, in my case, each task is a class, so I dont know how I can connect to the serial port and then share the access. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: the concurrency has to be against threads of a single process, or rather against separate processes running in the same machine? in the first case it would be pretty simple, but the second one is very complex.

Comment: It is against threads of a single process. A single app, has two tasks which need to access the serial port, at the moment I use a helper class to access the Serial. The helper class, connects to the hardware and listens. As I cannot share a single instance of this class, I don't know how to implement the mutex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the "lock" at the very beginning of this class: http://cetdevelop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V2/Cet/IO/Cet.IO.Serial/SerialPortClient.cs